# Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la calse principal

Tags: java, compilacion

El problema es al ejecutar el programa, pongo en la consola `cmd` javac y me sale el `jdk` instalado y todo, en el editor que uso [geany](/questions/tagged/geany) también me aparece que la compilación tuvo éxito.

Compilo mediante

```
javac HolaMundo.java
```

Al darle a ejecutar con el siguiente comando:

```
 java HolaMundo
```

me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
public class HolaMundo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
    }
}
```

Comment: El programa que hice en java es este, no tiene ningún problema :

Comment: Agrega tu codigo a tu pregunta

Comment: @jose ¿Puedes mostrar los comandos que usas para ejecutar el programa? Tu programa funciona bien.

Comment: @jose No estás parado en el directorio donde se encuentra la clase compilada (`HolaMundo.class`).

Comment: ¿Estas usando `java -jar (ruta-a-tu-jar)` o sólo estás haciendo doble click?

Comment: parece que Jose se fué...

Comment: Perdonad, los comandos que uso son javac HolaMundo.java (compilar) y java HolaMundo (ejecutar), uso geany por si os sirve de algo

Comment: No entiendo @Awes0meM4n, nunca utilize -jar en la ruta de comandos.

Comment: @PaulVargas y como podria solucionarlo entonces?

Answer (score 1):

Pueden se varios problemas pero creo puede tener que ver con el classpath.

Verifica que tu IDE (en este caso es geany) tenga correctamente configuradas las opciones de configuración. Según:

https://ericplayground.com/2015/06/07/how-to-configure-geany-to-run-java/

Geany debería configurarse algo así:

En **“Build”->“Set Build Commands”** define los siguientes comandos:

```
Compile:

“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javac” “%d\%f”

Execute:

“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java” “-classpath” “%d” “%e”
```

Sin embargo, si recién estás partiendo te recomiendo compilar y ejecutar desde la misma línea de comandos. Así vas a aprender mejor, tendrás mayor control y saber que es lo que pasa cuando debas debugear.

Prueba primero, abre tu consola y verifica la compilación y ejecución desde ahí, luego configura las opciones de tu IDE.

```
C:\> cd PATH_HASTA_TU_APP
C:\PATH_HASTA_TU_APP> javac HolaMundo.java 
C:\PATH_HASTA_TU_APP> dir # verifica que se haya creado el archivo HolaMundo.class
C:\PATH_HASTA_TU_APP> java HolaMundo
```

donde, PATH_HASTA_TU_APP es la ruta al directorio de tu aplicación. Por ejemplo:

```
C:\Users\jose\> cd myFirstJavaApp
C:\Users\jose\myFirstJavaApp>
```

o

```
C:\Users\jose\> cd C:\Users\jose\myFirstJavaApp
C:\Users\jose\myFirstJavaApp>
```

ambos casos hacen lo mismo.

Comment: Si es posible, te pediría que ampliases tu respuesta para no ser tan dependiente de los enlaces. Piensa que si esos enlaces, por la razón que sea, dejan de estar disponibles, tu respuesta no será útil para nadie.

Comment: Ya he realizado algunos cambios.

Comment: @molavec gracias, pero parece ser que sigue sin ir, me da error al poner los comando de compile y execute que me diste, y pobre solo con el execute (porque es el que falla) y me sigue dando error, este en concreto: El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos. Presione una tecla para continuar...

Comment: @molavec como puedo poner lo de PATH_HASTA_TU_APP, perdona soy nuevo en programación, como puedo encontrar la ruta ?

Comment: @jose No te preocupes. PATH_HASTA_TU_APP, debes reemplazarlo por la ruta completa o relativa del directorio donde esta tu aplicación. Mira este articulo sencillo: http://es.wikihow.com/cambiar-directorios-en-el-Command-Prompt.

Comment: @jose no temas a ingresar a la consola de terminal de windows. Es parte esencial a la hora de programar y va a ahorrarte muchas frustraciones a la hora de buscar errores. Incluso aprenderás nuevas cosas y te sentirás todo un hacker.

Comment: @jose edité al respuesta.

Comment: @molavec hice todos los pasos que me pusiste arriba, me sale el dir y el HolaMundo.class, me compila, pero por desgracia no me ejecuta . Si te sirve de algo, un amigo me dijo un truco para ejecutarlo que es el siguiente :      java(espacio)-cp(espacio).(espacio)nombredelprograma. Pero me gustaria que me fuera desde el geany como a todo el mundo :(

Comment: @jose  por ejemplo el hacer este ejercicio te ayudará a entender el ClassPath. La opción que te indicó tu amigo es para añadir la carpeta en el classpath, es decir, java intentará buscar en la carpeta actual la clase java. Cuando se desarrolla en Java definir el PATH y el CLASSPATH es una de las primeras cosas que causa bastante conflicto en windows, a diferencia de linux o mac. El entender para que sirven estas variables y donde se configuran te ayudará a entender que son las "variables de entorno" y como son utilizadas por los distintos sistemas operativos.

Comment: @jose  Es de seguro que esto es lo primero que debes configurar en windows antes de programar en Java y fue algo con lo que me costó partir también. De seguro si resuelves esto podrás ejecutar java desde cualquier IDE.

Comment: Que ejercicio? Perdon por la tardanza, temas de estudios @molavec

Comment: @jose el ejercicio de configurar las variables de entorno de tu PC.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a lanzar tu `.jar` con el siguiente comando desde la consola de Windows:

```
java -jar C://HolaMundo.jar
```

Con eso suele ser suficiente para saber dónde buscar tu clase principal si dices que está bien compilado. Si no funcionara y te sale otro mensaje añadelo a tu pregunta.

NOTA: El comando sirve si tu `jar` esta en C: y el archivo se llama `HolaMundo.jar`. Si no deberás de cambiarlo como proceda.

Comment: Efectivamente, me pone "error:Unable to access jarfile C: "

Comment: ¿Cuando compilas lo haces para generar un jar ejecutable? ¿Has puesto la ruta completa del jar? (pon en tu comentario el comando exacto que has usado para lanzarlo)

Comment: javac HolaMundo.java (compila) (lo hace, da un salto de linea) y despues java HolaMundo   PD: el .jar lo tengo en : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin

Comment: Si no me contestas exactamente a lo que te pregunto es imposible que te pueda ayudar: 1.- ¿Cuando compilas lo haces para generar un jar ejecutable? 2.- Ponme **exactamente** el comando que usas para **ejecutar** el jar (un ejemplo sería `java -jar "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\HolaMundo.jar"`) NOTA: **Es importante usar las comillas para que use los espacios, etc...**

Comment: @Awe0meM4n Mmmmm creo que si pero no estoy seguro, el comando que uso es: javac Holamundo.java y ejecutar: java HolaMundo (perdona si no contesto correctamente, como ya digo, estoy empezando) saludos

Comment: oh, para ejecutar igual te refieres al classpath? en la ruta de variables le tengo esto: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin

Comment: El comando sirve tambien si y solo si has definido un archivo MANIFEST.MF donde esté definida la clase principal. Si no, es mejor usar `java -cp <ubicación del jar> <nombre de la clase principal`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando generas una clase en *Java*, debes compilarla antes de ejecutarla.

La *JVM* trabaja con una serie de librerías que componen la distribución estándar más todo el *ClassPath* que le agregues.

Si el comando: `java HolaMundo` no lo estás ejecutando sobre la carpeta donde está el archivo **.class**, vas a tener que incluirlo en el *ClassPath*. Si hablamos de una clase sola, la manera más fácil es poner la ruta directa al directorio.